# Wordpress connection error when update PHP5.4 and having MySQL4.1+

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, password-encryption

I have quite a few problems with the page Im helping fix. Notice Im not that experienced in WordPress. Right now Im trying to use Php5.4 globally on my WordPress I have installed. But then comes an error that my Database user and password might be wrong. I changed the password as instructed in quite a few posts from some time ago. But that wont fix the problem. Right now my wordpress does work with the Php5.2 and Mysql4.1+ if thats got anything to do with the problem. I cant update the mysql cause of the server my wordpress is in. I read that the problem with having php5.4 and mysql5.1 is that there are some compatibility issues with the hashing of the password. Can anyone point me in the right direction. I need to upgrade my php to 5.4 cause I need to install a plugin which needs it.

When I read the error .log, this is what pops up:

```
[01-Jul-2015 16:47:56 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using the old insecure authentication. Please use an administration tool to reset your password with the command SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('your_existing_password'). This will store a new, and more secure, hash value in mysql.user. If this user is used in other scripts executed by PHP 5.2 or earlier you might need to remove the old-passwords flag from your my.cnf file in /home/hfeuchte/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1142
[01-Jul-2015 16:48:00 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using the old insecure authentication. Please use an administration tool to reset your password with the command SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('your_existing_password'). This will store a new, and more secure, hash value in mysql.user. If this user is used in other scripts executed by PHP 5.2 or earlier you might need to remove the old-passwords flag from your my.cnf file in /home/hfeuchte/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1142
```

As I said Ive already tried changing the password, updating it, and even creating a new user to see if the password grabs the necessary hash for the PHP5.4 to read. If there is anything else I can try, please do suggest :P Thanks for your time :D

Comment: If you can't update MySQL then get a different server to migrate to. Even a local one will do if you can upgrade MySQL afterwards.

Comment: how did you change the password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well with help of a moderator from WordPress. I finally changed the password via SSH and made sure the password was saved in a format of 41 characters. Then activated the PHP5.4 and wala it worked :P If the version of MySQL was a bit higher maybe changing the password via the SQL Query or the CPanel might have worked. Just to make sure use SSH. For me it worked.